# Authenticate via LDAP fails when using TLS

Tags: java, ldap

I found several discussions about this issue in the net but none of them worked for me.
I am trying to authenticate via LDAP using TLS connection.
I get contradicted responses when using ldapsearch command and Java code.
In the ldapsearch command, searching with TLS works and fails without it,
While in the Java code the standard LDAPS connection works and TLS fails.

Here's the ldapsearch results:

With TLS:

> > /usr/bin/ldapsearch -h ldap.server.com -Z -x -D "#BIND_DN#" -W -b "#SEARCH_BASE#" -s sub "(cn=#USERNAME#)"
> >         Enter LDAP Password: XXXXXXXX
> >         ....
> >         mail: test.user@ldap.server.com
> >         result: 0 Success

Without TLS:

> > /usr/bin/ldapsearch -h ldap.server.com -p 636 -x -D "#BIND_DN#" -W -b "#SEARCH_BASE#" -s sub  "(cn=#USERNAME#)"
> >         Enter LDAP Password: XXXXXXXXX 
> >  
> >         ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

And here are the Java results:

Without TLS:

```
>>java -cp lib com.myapp.toolkit.auth.LDAPTestKit
[LDAPTestKit] found authenContext.
[LDAPTestKit] Authentication Success
[LDAPTestKit] Found attributes:
[LDAPTestKit] mail : test.user@ldap.server.com

....
```

With TLS:

```
>>java -cp lib com.myapp.toolkit.auth.LDAPTestKit
ERROR [main] [] [LDAPTestKit] Initial binding - Failure
                [LDAP: error code 1 - TLS already started]

javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - TLS already started]; remaining name ''
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3107)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.extendedOperation(LdapCtx.java:3192)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.extendedOperation(InitialLdapContext.java:164)
```

I use the following code:

```
bindEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
bindEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
bindEnv.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
bindEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://ldap.server.com:636");    
bindEnv.put("java.naming.security.principal", "#BIND_DN#");
bindEnv.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "#BIND_PASS#");
LdapContext bindCtx = new InitialLdapContext(bindEnv, null);
// So far O.K
StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse) bindCtx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest()); 
// Exception!!!
tls.negotiate();
```

I tried it with "ldap://" instead of "ldaps://" but got the same response.
Is it a certificate issue? Or is there anything I am missing in the code?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without `StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse) bindCtx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest()); 
tls.negotiate();`?

Comment: Yes, it works without it.

Comment: And that is what you wanted, right?

Comment: I don't know, the cusotmer requires a TLS connection. I am trying to replicate the ldapsearch command which the customer uses.

Comment: If you set `ldaps` binding URL then it will be in an SSL channel, which should be sufficient.

Comment: So, the ldapsearch should work with TLS but my application can use LDAPS instead? I cannot make TLS work even when I use ldap and not ldaps.

Comment: SSL and TLS are almost the same, and both of them creates a secure channel. Sometimes people are simply mixing them up or using them for the same thing. From your perspective it doesn't make any difference to use TLS or SSL, the result will be essentially the same.

Comment: You can try to fix the TLS too. You should use `ldap://` and `port 389` to start TLS negotation.

Comment: I tried it and got "LDAP: error code 13 - confidentiality required"

Comment: Now that is a brand new error for you to solve :) It might be easier to live with SSL;)

Comment: So basically I can declare that I support SSL connection and that should be enough?

Comment: Depends on your client... I assume the goal is to avoid open LDAP connnections. Now the SSL is perfect for this! I'm using LDAPS and not TLS with every application I know. Most of the off-the-shelf apps are supporting LDAP over SSL and not TLS.

Comment: O.K, I think that's what I'll do as well. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The StartTLS extended operation is meant to establish the TLS layer over an existing plain LDAP connection.
As Balint Bako pointed out yesterday, it is not needed if you are connecting to LDAPS, i.e. establishing a TLS connection to the socket to use LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [JNDI Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/ext/starttls.html)

We have used their example with good outcomes.